# good practices in windows server 2008 r2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I'm not a native English speaker... so, my English is not perfect. Please bear with me.

1. Is it a good practice to install multiple server roles in one machine?
2. If the answer is yes, what server roles can I mix?
3. Are there any server roles that cannot be mixed, if so, which ones?
4. For the server roles that cannot be mixed. Should I virtualize them (Hyper-V Server 2008 R2) or have them in their own machine?
5. I'm thinking in buying MS Forefront Treat Management 2010 and MS Exchange 2010 Standard. Should I virtualize them or have them in their own machine?

All answers and opinions are appreciated.

Thank you for everything

Jorge

Comment: No apologies necessary. Your English is better than what I see posted by many native English speakers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is good practice to install
>   multiple server roles in one machine?

Yes, you can mix roles, (e.g. Domain Controller and Certificate Authority are two that are often mixed). For some you HAVE to mix. For example, there's no point in installing the Network Load Balancing role without installing something else (say, SQL or IIS)

> If the answer is yes, what server
>   roles can I mix?

There is no definitive list, but Small Business Server mixes almost ALL the roles into the one server. This may not be recommended for your deployment, but it proves that almost all of them can be mixed.

> There are some server roles that
>   cannot be mixed, if so, which ones?

There are some that you *shouldn't* mix, such as Exchange and Domain Controller.

> For the server roles that cannot be mixed. Should I virtualize em
>   (Hyper-V Server 2008 R2) or have them
>   in their own machine?

Virtualising is great in this regards. If you have Sever 2008 then you already have Hyper-V, and if are running Enterprise then you're entitled to 4 virtual instances. If you don't use them, they're going to waste. But there is an overhead, so you better make sure your hardware is up to it (especially with RAM).

> I'm thinking in buying MS Forefront
>   Treat Management 2010 and MS Exchange
>   2010 Standard. Should I virtualize
>   them or have em in their own machine?

TMG should be physical, but there's nothign to stop you from making it virtual if your gateway is ethernet based (i.e. you don't need any special hardware, as passing through hardware is impossible in Hyper-V).

Regarding exchange, it most definately can be virtualised, but whether or not you should virtualise it depends greatly on your number of expected users and the kind of hardware you have.